# Geometry from curve

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a closed spline in 3D and wish to create a flat mesh according to this spline. The points are in 3D, but are constrained to a plane. Either a completely flat or an extruded one is ok. I understand I need to supply some kind of direction for the mesh to extend in and can provode either two splines and then I want to fill in the hole between those with triangles, or I can provide a normal direction for each point on the spline for the mesh to extend to. How would I go about this, I see there are lots of classes already in THREE.js, but I can't understand how to use these. Should I make my own, and how would I go about that?

Comment: See http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_geometry_shapes.html

Comment: these are 2D shapes which are very different. I guess I need to then first transform my points to an axis aligned plane, and then create the geometry and then transform back? Perhaps easier to just to some special code for this?